# Logstash timestamp appearing as text in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using Elasticsearch 7.3.1 and Logstash 7.3.1. I am trying to make a field of mine as the Elasticsearch timestamp using the date filter. The data is being inserted properly but the type of `@timestamp` is coming `text`. How do I fix this?

My input timestamp is like `1567408605794750813`. My code is:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "x.x.x.x"
    index => "raw"
    docinfo => true
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    convert => {
      "timestamp" => "integer"
    }
  }
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "UNIX_MS", "ISO8601"]
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "logs-%{app_name}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```

After running the mapping API, I get

```
"@timestamp" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "fields" : {
    "keyword" : {
      "type" : "keyword",
      "ignore_above" : 256
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code,

```
date {
    match => [ "[timestamp]", "UNIX" ]
    target => "[@timestamp]"
}
```